# Formatting text as CamelCase in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, replace, camelcasing

I would like to get from lines such as this:

```
#define FACILITY_USERMODE_HYPERVISOR  53
```

to a line such as this, for use in an enum:

```
zFacilityUsermodeHypervisor = FACILITY_USERMODE_HYPERVISOR,
```

A quick regex replace does half the trick, is there a quick way to get the complete result?

```
Regex:   #define (FACILITY_\w+)\s+(\d+)
Replace: $1 = $1,
```

This leaves me with

```
FACILITY_USERMODE_HYPERVISOR = FACILITY_USERMODE_HYPERVISOR,
```

How would I convert the first part to CamelCase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely too difficult to achieve with VS S&R that does not support `\l` / `\u` and `\L` / `\U` ... `\E` operators in the replacement pattern.

I suggest acheiving it with **3 steps in Notepad++**:

- Duplicate the identifier you need to turn to CaMeL case with `#define (FACILITY_\w+)(?=\s+\d+)` regex ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/iE2yS4/1)). Your `#define FACILITY_USERMODE_HYPERVISOR  53` will turn into `#define FACILITY_USERMODE_HYPERVISOR %%% FACILITY_USERMODE_HYPERVISOR  53`.
- Apply the CaMeL case on the first occurrence of the identifier after `#define` with `(?:#define\s+|(?!^)\G)\K_?([A-Za-z])([^\W_]*)_?(?=[\w\s]*%%%)` regex and `\u$1\L$2\E` replacement. So, `#define FACILITY_USERMODE_HYPERVISOR %%% FACILITY_USERMODE_HYPERVISOR  53` will turn into `#define FacilityUsermodeHypervisor %%% FACILITY_USERMODE_HYPERVISOR  53`.

[image]

- The last step is just getting your desired output: removing what you do not need and adding the equal sign: use `#define (Facility\w*)\s+%%%\s+(\w+)\s+\d+` regex with the `z$1 = $2,` replacement ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/bS6vB7/1)).